# How to record call in android ? (old methods not working)

Tags: android

Asking my questions quickly.

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile((audioFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```

This code works on note5 but not on s8+. I cannot record other sides voice.

I cant use AudioSource.VOICE_CALL or AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK and AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK because of CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission problem.

But ACR app successfully record all conversations so it is possible.

NOTE: I do not think the format or encoder is related to this topic

Full code:

```
private void startRecord() {

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();

    File recordDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/CallRecord");

    if (!recordDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        recordDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    audioFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/CallRecord",
            ts + ".aac");

    recordedFilePath = audioFile.getPath();
    RecordInfo.recordPath = recordedFilePath;

    tsLong = null;
    ts = null;
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile((audioFile.getAbsolutePath()));

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private void stopRecord() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.release();
}
```

Comment: check this out:
https://github.com/rjeffm/CallRecorder

Comment: mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

I cannot use this because of permission.

Capturing from VOICE_CALL source requires the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.

Answer (score 0):

Start Audio Recording

```
 public void startAudioRecording(View view) throws IOException {  
        //Create file to save recording
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
        try {  
          audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", dir);  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
          Log.e(TAG, "external storage access error");  
          return;  
        }  
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();  
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);  
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);  
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);  
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());  
        mRecorder.prepare();  
        mRecorder.start();  
      }
```

Stop Audio Recording

```
 public void stopAudioRecording(View view) {  
        mRecorder.stop();  
        mRecorder.release();  
      }
```